# UIWebView streaming youtube does not go to fullscreen on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, youtube, fullscreen

I have a button that unhides a UIWebView and then streams a youtube video.  On the iphone it works fine and pressing the play button goes straight to fullscreen and then when its finished hitting the done button hides the UIWebView and return control to app.

However when I try the same on iPad, pressing play does not automatically go to fullscreen (you can hit the fullscreen control but I dont want users to have that option) - is there a way to do this please?

The code I have is:

```
- (IBAction)topButton:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:)     name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
    videoWebView.hidden=NO;
    NSString *embedcode = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"youtubeEmbedCodeBeginner"];
    [[self videoWebView]loadHTMLString:embedcode baseURL:nil];
}
```

and:

```
-(void)youTubeFinished:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // your code here
    videoWebView.hidden=YES;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try This

selector:@selector(someSelector) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification" object:nil]

// For iOS 4.3 and above:
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification

// For iOS 4.2 and below:
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullcreenNotification

Thanks